# Has Replication Stalled?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

**What Happened:**

I reinitialized a subscription 16 hours ago. I had about 1.2M records to transfer, so I was expecting it to take a while. The Replication Monitor was saying "*N transactions with N commands were delivered*" for hours, so I figured everything was OK.

**The Issue:**

This morning when I check the Replication Monitor, I see this:
[image: Snapshot Not Yet Available]

Oh no!, I exclaim, thinking I need to reinitialize replication with a newer snapshot to avoid pulling 1.2M rows. But I look at the other Tab on the Replication Monitor, and I see this:

[image: Transaction Delivered]

**Question:**

I'm wondering why Transactions are being delivered, despite Replication Monitor complaining about the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly but it looks like something went wrong during the reinitialization process.  Transactions are flowing from Publisher to Distributor but the Subscriber is requiring a new snapshot.  I'd recommend generating a new snapshot and then it will be reapplied by the Distribution Agent.  At that point you should be back in sync.